# Terraform azure sql database Backup storage redundancy with Zone-redundant backup storage

Tags: database, azure, terraform

I need to configure in terraform for azure sql database the backup storage redundancy but with the option Zone-redundant backup storage, I couldn't finde the way in the documentation

thanks

ok, my code is

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "ms" {
          name                         = lower(var.server_name)
          resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name //azurerm_resource_group.func-rg.name
          location                     = var.location//azurerm_resource_group.func-rg.location
          version                      = var.server_version
          administrator_login          = var.admin_login
          administrator_login_password = var.admin_password
          connection_policy            = var.sql_server_connection_policy //connection policy default
          tags                         = var.tags
        }
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "md" {
  name           = var.database_name
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.ms.id
  //collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  //license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = 250
  read_scale     = false
  //sku_name       = "BC_Gen5_2" //cambiar este valor a DTU
  zone_redundant = true
  storage_account_type = "ZRS"
  threat_detection_policy { //enable Microsoft Defender for SQL 
    state                      = "Enabled"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "pe" {
  name                = var.private_endpoint_name 
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = var.private_service_connection_name 
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.ms.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["sqlServer"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @DanielVegaRuiz, I have updated the answer , providing the solution for the error you are getting . Please modified code with storage account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `storage_account_type = "ZRS"` for setting **storage backup redundancy**.

When ***threat detection policy*** has `state = enabled` , you have to add **Storage endpoint** and **Storage account access key** as well . So , You have to **create a storage account** and provide the parameters like below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "exampletest-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "ansumantestsa123"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "exampleansuman-sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "admin"
  administrator_login_password = "password"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "test" {
  name           = "acctest-db-d"
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  #collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  #license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = 250
  read_scale     = false
  #sku_name       = "BC_Gen5_2"
  zone_redundant = true
  storage_account_type = "ZRS"
  threat_detection_policy { //enable Microsoft Defender for SQL 
    state                      = "Enabled"
    storage_endpoint = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_blob_endpoint
    storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  }
}
```

**Ouput:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have this issue Error: setting database threat detection policy for Database: (Name "exSqlDataBaseName" / Server Name "server-dvegarui" / Resource Group "Pruebas-SmartUtility"): sql.DatabaseSecurityAlertPoliciesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="DataSecurityInvalidUserSuppliedParameter" Message="storageAccountAccessKey 
parameter can not be null when storageEndpoint parameter is not null\r\nParameter name: storageAccountAccessKey"

Comment: @DanielVegaRuiz, please add the whole terraform code you are using.

Comment: ok!! I edited my post with the code

Answer (score 0):

│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on ../Terraform-Modules/SqlDatabase/Sqldatabase.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_sql_database" "sqldb":
│   10:     storage_account_type = "LRS"

getting this error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).